# Huawei mate 20 lite bootloader-unlock doesn't work due to FRP

Tags: bootloader-lock, frp

I've got two huawei mate 20 lites in front of me, and I have the bootloader codes to unlock them.
But when I use adb fastboot to unlock them I get the message "Cannot unlock bootloader, you need to unlock FRP first" not with those exact words, but something like that.
How can I unlock the bootloader with the codes that i have without entering the phones settings to enable usb debugging? I feel like I've scanned the whole internet by now. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Maybe our [frp tag wiki](/tags/frp/info) and [answered questions tagged frp](/search?q=[frp]+answers%3A1) are good starting points?

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=cNOlGTg0fMw

Answer (score 1):

have you enabled `allow OEM bootloader unlocking` in settings, it is in dev options

Here's some steps:
(optional, to enable dev options):
settings >> about phone >> (tap build no. 7 times)

enable oem unlocking:
settings >> system >> advanced >> developer options >> allow oem unlocking(turn it on)

Screenshot:
[image: Allow OEM UNLOCKING]

(mine is disabled as I have a unlocked bootloader)

Comment: The problem is that my friend whom i'm trying to help unlock the bootloader for, forgot/lost his google account. The only code / password he has for the phone is the bootloader code! I don't know what to do here! Is it impossible since i cant get into the settings?

Comment: I can't reach settings. I'm locked out of the phone, we thought we could unlock bootloader without using settings? Like with ADB? But in ADB it tells us to unlock FRP first but we cant reach settings we forgot the codes for the phone!